# Failed to restore eloquent model after it has been un-serialized (Laravel 5.4)

Tags: php, laravel-5, serialization

I cannot understand why an un-serialized eloquent model cannot be saved in the database table.

I am trying to restore previous versions of a "document" which are represented by an `App\Document` model. Before each document model is updated the previous "version" is serialized and stored in a different table so it can be retrieved in the future.

When I retrieve the serialized model and un-serialize it (unserialize()) I am calling the save() method on the model but nothing happens.

The code:

```
$targetModel = unserialize($serializedModel);                       
$modelSaved = $targetModel->save();
```

`$modelSaved` is always true but the row in the database table does not change.

After looking at the API i saw that when we call save() on a model then only if the model exists and is `dirty` will be updated.

Please note that if I 'dump' the `$targetModel` the properties `attributes` and `original` are the same and the call to `isDirty()` returns `false`.

I have also tried modifying an attribute of the un-serialized model so that `isDirty()` returns true but that has not changed anything.

Any ideas on how I can save the un-serialized model in the database? I am doing something wrong here, for sure.

Comment: You should not serialize whole objects. There are several problems you will run into. When the object definition changes (for example by renaming an attribute) you will not be able to deserialize it anymore. Normally it is better practice to serialize information that does not change, e.g. the id of you model. After unserializing you can re-load your entity from the database.

Comment: Good point @jascha, but I still don't understand why the call to save() fails. I will probably have to clone the documents table for keeping the previous versions of the documents?

Comment: You might wana hydrate it first, like cuppa noodles  `App\Document::hydrate($targetModel);`